# Change Cookie Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I'd to Change the lookout of the following cookiescript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"Meine Website verwendet Cookies um die Benutzerfreundlichkeit zu erhöhen.","dismiss":"Ich stimme zu","learnMore":"More info","link":null};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.10/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
```

Is it possible for me to insert an image as a button instead of the text button? I would also have to change the background color and the intensity of the color.

Thanks for your help.

Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a custom layout and do whatever you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.10/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    cookieconsent.initialise({
        layout: 'my-cool-layout',
        layouts: {
            'my-cool-layout': '<div class="my-cool-layout">\
            {{ header }}{{ message }}{{ compliance }}{{ pictureOfCat }}</div>{{ close }}',
        },
        elements: {
            pictureOfCat: '<img href="http://placekitten/300/300" />',
        },
        content: {
            header: 'My awesome cat popup!'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Check out the library API: https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/javascript-api/

Hope it helps :)